# Check my proof of the ratio test

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

Q:
Prove that ratio test: $a_k\neq 0$ assume: $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{k+1}}{a_k}\right|:=r<1$$ Prove that the series must converge absolutely.

My proof thanks for any help just looking for a proof check:

\begin{align}
    &\mbox{choose} \ \epsilon: \ (a:=r-\epsilon) \ (b:=r+\epsilon) \ a,b\in(0,1) \notag \\ 
    &\implies \exists N: \ \forall n>N \ a<\left|\frac{a_{n-1}}{a_n}\right|<b \notag \\
    &\implies \exists N: \ \forall n > N \ |a_{n+1}|<b|a_n| \tag{1} \notag \\
    &\implies \exists N: \ \forall n > N \ |a_{n+c}|<b^c|a_n| \tag{Recursively apply (1)} \notag \\ 
    &\implies \sum^n_{c=1}|a_{N+c}|\leq\sum^n_{c=1}b^c|a_N| \notag \\
    &\implies \sum^\infty_{c=1}|a_{N+c}| \ \mbox{converges} \tag{By comp. test and geo. series} \\
    &\implies \sum^\infty_{n=1}|a_n| \ \mbox{converges} \tag{By reintroducing the removed finite part.}
\end{align}

Comment: Instead of "$\mbox{choose} \ \epsilon: \ (a:=r-\epsilon) \ (b:=r+\epsilon) \ a,b\in(0,1)$", simply choose $b\in(r,1).$

Comment: @AnneBauval Thanks I see this is a simplification. My logic works besides this inconcise?

Comment: Yes, fine!_____